# Php: sql query with CASE and multiple selection

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to query a database depending on the search criteria of the user, one of the criteria is the registered gender:  male or female.

However, the user can send as a criteria `male` `female` or `anything`. I am trying to select all rows when the user sends `anything`, but I am getting empty result.

Here are some of my trials, none of them seems to work, but it works fine for the cases of `male` `female`

```
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM UsersInfo 
            WHERE gender = CASE '$et_gender'
                WHEN 'male' THEN 'male'
                WHEN 'female' THEN 'female'
                WHEN 'anything' THEN 'female' AND 'male'
                            END";


$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM UsersInfo 
            WHERE gender = CASE '$et_gender'
                WHEN 'male' THEN 'male'
                WHEN 'female' THEN 'female'
                WHEN 'anything' THEN SELECT * FROM UsersInfo
                            END";


$query = "SELECT * 
                FROM UsersInfo 
                WHERE gender = CASE '$et_gender'
                    WHEN 'male' THEN 'male'
                    WHEN 'female' THEN 'female'
                    WHEN 'anything' THEN * 
                                END";
```

Comment: It's generally much better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in WHERE clauses.

Comment: @jarlh thanks...Im not very expert in sql...so CASE sounded like exactly what I needed...but yeah maybe you are right

Comment: Try printing your query out to the screen, see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
 $query =   "SELECT * 
    FROM UsersInfo 
    WHERE (gender = '$et_gender' AND '$et_gender' IN ('male', 'female')) OR ('$et_gender'='anything')"
```

Depending on the values I suppose you could abbreviate it too (but do some checks):

```
  $query =   "SELECT * 
        FROM UsersInfo 
        WHERE (gender = '$et_gender') OR ('$et_gender'='anything')"
```

Comment: thanks, it looks good, im not very expert in sql but I will try it

Answer (score 1):

What I see is that, you don't need to mention any filter condition at all and your query could just be

```
SELECT * FROM UsersInfo
```

(OR) use a `IN` operator like

```
WHERE gender IN ('male','female','anything')
```

(OR) per your posted code use a equality operator `=`

```
WHERE gender = '$et_gender'
```

Comment: no man...If for example user sends `male` in criteria, I should just get MALE users from table...the same for `female`...and ALL of them for `anything`